# about "by" followed by a number or amount of change

Tags: prepositions, difference

Which of the following sentence is correct ? If both are correct, do they have the same meaning ?

*The company's sales grew **by** 70% year-on-year to US$100 m.*

*The company's sales grew 70% year-on-year to US$100 m.*

Comment: They're both valid, and mean exactly the same thing. They're also about equally common, so there's no special reason to prefer one over the other (i.e. - the preposition ***by*** is *entirely* optional here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **By** - (Preposition) Indicating the amount or size of a margin.
>
> **Ex** -
>
> 1. *The shot missed her by miles.*
> 2. *The raising of VAT by 2.5%*
>
> **Percent** - (adjective) by, in or for every hundred (symbol %)
>
> **Ex**  -
>
> 1. *House prices rose five per cent last year*

Here I have quoted the dictionary for both **"by"** and **"percentage"**. It's apparent that in the definition of **"percentage"**, the preposition **"by"** is already included. So we can skip in our sentence the preposition **"by"** before **"percentage"**. And so before **"percentage"**, the use of **"by"** is redundant or optional.

Comment: The idea that ***by*** becomes optional ***because of the word "percent"*** is completely wrong here. *His salary rose [by] a thousand pounds, Prices increased [by] a little, Sales dropped [by] a little during lockdown,...* No percentages there.