# Can 'by' be omitted in "rose by 30%"?

Tags: prepositions, numbers

> The company's annual revenues rose **by** 30%.

I'd like to ask if the preposition ***by*** there is indispensable. Is it wrong with it left out?

Comment: *Profits **went up** 10%, The FTSE **fell** 5%, Prices **increased** a little.* The preposition ***by*** is optional in all those examples as well as yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use preposition "by"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21342/when-to-use-preposition-by) It specifically asks about optional ***by*** in *The company's sales grew [by] 70%*

Comment: Also be aware of the distinction between a percentage rise and a rise by a number of percentage *points*. It doesn't apply to annual revenues, but if you were talking about profitability you might say it "rose 30%" (eg from 10% to 13%) vs "rose by 30 percentage points" (ie from 10% to 40%).

Comment: Thank you all, guys. @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I couldn't that thread, even after I searched a lot. I appreciate your help, your answering and providing the link.